# Using aws lambda to handle real time requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I used to think aws lambda was best suited to handle background tasks which did not require immediate results.  However more and more I have seen aws lambda being used to handle real-time requests as well, for example fetch users from a db in a http get.

API Gateway -> AWS Lambda -> Results

Is this a standard approach or is this the improper use of lambda ?

Comment: Yes, its standard approach.

Comment: My concern here is that is this performant enough when compared to a direct invocation ? I know it depends on the situation but when compared to the traditional direct invocation?

Comment: I don't have any benchmarks, but if you want to make your lambda accessible publicly (or part of some private REST API), there is no such thing as "direct" invocation. You have to use api gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Use of API Gateway to provide a front end for the Lambda function invocation is the standard way of executing Lambda function code on the fly. If you are concerned about the cold starts on the function; and want to minize the latency, you can consider [Provisioned Concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/aws-lambda-announces-provisioned-concurrency/) to keep 'n' active containers at a small cost.